# HTML A href '#' Not Working?

Tags: html

This is My Html Code For Back To Top.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Back To Top</title>
</head>
<body id='backtotop'>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <a href="#backtotop" id='moveback' style='display:none;'>Backtotop</a>
<button id='Clickme'>Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Clickme").click(function(){
            $("#moveback").click();
            $("#moveback").trigger('click');
        });
    }); 
}(jQuery));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on `Backtotop` link is working find on desktop. but when i try to tablet or mobile this is not working. when i click on link it dosen't move back to top on tablet or mobile.

please help.

Thank you.

Comment: In every browser on Android (Chrome, FF, Opera, *Browser*), this works fine for me. Which browser specifically does this not work for?

Comment: check out this page: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?259280-anchor-tag-not-working-in-safari-(ios)-for-Iphone-iTouch-iPad. Do you have any javascript events attached to links?

Comment: i update my question please check this is not working on firefox or chrome. or tablet. please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is called internal linking Where hyper link is within same web page.
The code we mostly use is

`<A NAME="LINK"> </A>`

Where LINK is the name of that position.

Example:

```
<body>
<H4>Click here to go to bottom <A HREF="#BOTTOM"> bottom </a> of the page </H4>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>  
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<A NAME="BOTTOM"><h1>This si bottom</h1></A>
</body>
```

And if this is not working then you can implement scroll function like :

```
function scrollWindow()
{
window.scrollTo(x,y);
}


//   where
 //  x= for horizontal co-ordinates,y=for vertical cordinates
//x=100,y=600--try this

execute this function onclick of your link

     <ul>
          <li><a href="#backtotop" onclick=scrollwindow>Backtotop</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And also you can use the ID attribute in place of the NAME attribute in the  tag to name the section in a Web page.

**Please NOTE:**  Many elements on page are floating elements. As a result, the browser cannot find a precise point to link to if the anchor target is not within a floated element. In other words, if the anchor tag is outside a floating element, and you have many floating elements on your page, internal links may not work properly. To fix this, place your anchor target within one of the floating elements.